# Tikz: Arranging of a Table with Tikz elements

Tags: tables, circuitikz

I'm trying to set an Table with CircuiTikz Elements.

The table looks like this:

[image: Table_now]

and i want it to look like that:

[image: Table]

So i want to have everything centered in one row, and a newline at the "leitend" and "sperrend" part. The Circuitikz elements should appear centered. I have drawn a Picture to visualize my wish.

I dont know how i can get that in Tikz, so help would be really nice!

Here is the Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & Ersatzschaltbild:
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Diode:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}   
    \\ \hline
    MOSFET:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}
    & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
      sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
    IGBT:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
        sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd split up the last column into two columns. One for "leitend" and a second for "sperrend". With `\multicolumn` you can merge the two columns in the "Kondensator"  and "Spule" rows.

Comment: Yes thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can nest tabulars.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & Ersatzschaltbild:
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Diode:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{tabular}{cc}
leitend &
    sperrend\\ 
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}   
    \end{tabular}\\ \hline
    MOSFET:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}
    &  \begin{tabular}{cc} leitend &
      sperrend \\  
      \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}
    \end{tabular}
    \\ \hline
    IGBT:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & \begin{tabular}{cc} leitend &
      sperrend \\   \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
        & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz} 
        \end{tabular}        
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to properly align the circuits, you may want to put both in one `circuitikz` and work with local bounding boxes. This allows you to center things according to the `circuitikz` rules, i.e. align the circuits.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begingroup
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},every
picture/.append style={execute at end picture={\path (current bounding
box.north) -- ++ (0,2pt) (current bounding
box.south) -- ++ (0,-2pt);}}}% fixed position of current bounding box
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & Ersatzschaltbild:
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Diode:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & 
    \begin{circuitikz}
       \begin{scope}[local bounding box=leitend]
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
    \end{scope}
    \path let \p1=($(leitend.east)-(leitend.west)$) in
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=sperrend,xshift=\mywidth/2+2.6cm]
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
    \end{scope}     
    \path (leitend.north) node[above]{leitend} (sperrend|-leitend.north)
    node[above]{sperrend};
        \end{circuitikz}   
    \\ \hline
    MOSFET:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}
    & 
    \begin{circuitikz}
       \begin{scope}[local bounding box=leitend]
        \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
    \end{scope}
    \path let \p1=($(leitend.east)-(leitend.west)$) in
     (leitend.center) --++ (-\mywidth/2,0)
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=sperrend,xshift=\mywidth/2+2.6cm]
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
    \end{scope}     
    \path (leitend.north) node[above]{leitend} (sperrend|-leitend.north)
    node[above]{sperrend};
        \end{circuitikz}   
    \\ \hline
    IGBT: & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    & \begin{circuitikz}
       \begin{scope}[local bounding box=leitend]
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
    \end{scope}
    \path let \p1=($(leitend.east)-(leitend.west)$) in
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mywidth{\x1}};
   \begin{scope}[local bounding box=sperrend,xshift=\mywidth/2+2.6cm]
       \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
       \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
    \end{scope}     
    \path (leitend.north) node[above]{leitend} (sperrend|-leitend.north)
    node[above]{sperrend};
        \end{circuitikz}   
            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\endgroup
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that looks good! Nice to know! But how do i get the "sperrend" tabular centered like in my drawn picture? and after that the "Kondensator" and "Spule" cells should be centered..

Comment: @adaptive For this I recommend putting these `circutikz` together in one `circuitikz` environment, see my update.

Comment: yes thanks, thats very intuitive!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a different version using `\multicolumn` and `\multirow` as well as 4 instead of 3 columns:

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

    \usepackage{multirow}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|cc|}
        \hline
        Bauteil:
        & Schaltbild:
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ersatzschaltbild:}
        \\ 
        \hline
        Spule:
        & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
            \end{circuitikz} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
            to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
            \end{circuitikz}} 
        \\ \hline
        \multirow{4}{*}{Diode:}
        & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
            \end{circuitikz}} 
        & leitend: 
        & sperrend:\\
        && \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
            to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
            \end{circuitikz}
         & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
    \label{tab:ESB}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}


Here is the code for the complete table:
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|cc|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Ersatzschaltbild:}
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{Diode:}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\
    && \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{MOSFET:}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}}
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\
    && \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
     & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{IGBT:}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}}
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\   
    && \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

With the help of the `cellspace` package you can also add a little bit of white space on the inside of each cell in order to prevent the images from overlapping with the horizontal lines. With the help of `\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=0.5ex]0,0)}}`, the two tikzpictures can also be aligned with respect to the horizontal lines, as suggested by [John Kormylo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512957/134144) and [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512933/tikz-arranging-of-a-table-with-tikz-elements/512936?noredirect=1#comment1297302_512936).

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{array,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt} 
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tikzset{baseline={([yshift=0.5ex]0,0)}}
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|ScSc|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{Ersatzschaltbild:}
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{Diode:}
    & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}} 
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\
    && \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{4}{*}{MOSFET:}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}}
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\
    && \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
     & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
    \multirow{5}{*}{IGBT:}
    & \multirow{5}{*}{\begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}}
    & leitend: 
    & sperrend:\\   
    && \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I have incorporated it into my answer. In previous tests, I also tried to vertically align the two circuits with respect to the horizontal line but was unfortunately unable to find the right command and therefore focused more on the alignment of the words.

Answer (score 3):

This addresses the vertical alignment, specifically aligning the leads instead of the boxes.  There are a number of ways to add space at the borders.  `\arraystretch` is a built in feature of tabular and (when large enough) makes every row the same height.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=calc]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors,straightvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\tikzset{baseline={(0,-0.5ex)}}% fixed position of current bounding box
\def\arraystretch{3}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Bauteil:
    & Schaltbild:
    & Ersatzschaltbild:
    \\ 
    \hline
    Kondensator:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [C,l=$C$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{C}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Spule:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [L,l=$L$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{L}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    \\ \hline
    Diode:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [D*,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz} 
    & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_D$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_\mathrm{D}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
    sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
        \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
        \end{circuitikz}   
    \\ \hline
    MOSFET:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to node[nigfete,rotate=90,scale=0.85](nigfet){} (0,0);
      \end{circuitikz}
    & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [R,l=$R_{\mathrm{on}}$,o-o] (2,0);
        \end{circuitikz}  
      sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
    IGBT:
    & \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to node[nigbt,rotate=90](nigigbt2){} (0,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
     & leitend: \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) to [V=$U_\mathrm{D}$,o-] (2,0)
        to [R,l=$r_{\mathrm{S}}$,-o] (4,0);
        \end{circuitikz}
        sperrend: \begin{circuitikz}
            \draw (0,0) to [short,-o] (0.5,0);
            \draw (1,0) to [short,o-] (1.5,0);
            \end{circuitikz}  
    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Elektronische Bauelemente und deren Ersatzschaltbilder}
\label{tab:ESB}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]